# Переадресация при 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Как сделать, что бы при неверном url происходила переадресация на главную страницу ? Я пытаюсь реализовать это добавлением в web.config :

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/uploadController/Index">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/uploadController/Index" />
</customErrors>
```

Но все равно получаю страницу с ошибкой при неправильном адресе :

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

UPD `RouteConfig` :

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
        routes.MapRoute("NotFound",
        "{*url}",
         new { controller = "uploadController", action = "Index" }
        );
    }
```

Контроллер `uploadController` распологает методом `Index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте код после всех маршрутов:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NotFound",
    "{*url}",
    new { controller = "uploadController", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: в web.config оставлять customErrors или нового маршрута достаточно?

Comment: В веб конфиг можно убрать customErrors

Comment: Все равно -` The resource cannot be found.`

Comment: А у вас точно существует контроллер uploadController с методом Index? И почему у вас uploadController с маленькой буквы?

Comment: да, точно. обновил вопрос. может ли иметь значение что приложение запущенo на localhost

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось достаточно простым. Пришлось создать новый контроллер :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index","upload");
}
```

Который и осуществляет переадресацию от неверных URL. А в файле Web.config 
необходимо добавить :

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Ooops/Index" />
</customErrors>
```

Так можно перенаправить запрос если в url есть некоторые ошибки. Однако если в url добавить точку и случайный символ то упадет стандартная 404 страница.